# Is there a backup/restore mechanism for Azure Network Security Groups (and their rules)?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

Building up Azure network security groups and rules requires a fair amount of work. My question is whether there is a way to backup them up.

I came across Get-AzureVNetConfig -ExportToFile which is a convenient way backup vnet settings. Restore can be done with Set-AzureVNetConfig -ConfigurationPath. In reality, this give a very nice way of writing a VNet spec (in XML) for a VNet.

I seeking for a XML based way of writing NSG rules. So I can backup/restore it at will.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommnd using Azure Resource Manager templates for this purpose. You can build json files that describe the NSG. Examples of templates with nsg can be found in the [quickstart gallery](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-nsg-dmz-in-vnet).
[More about Azure Resource Manager](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-overview/)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially everything in Azure is ARM scripts behind the scene. That is what declarative syntax is all about. So one [hardwork] way would be -

1. Use Azure PowerShell to export NSG ARM scripts with its rules
2. The powershell should also export associated Subnet or NIC information for better information capturing.
3. Schedule that script using Azure runbook in Azure automation account to export everyday/ every few hours.
4. Make sure that exported ARM scripts are uploaded to Azure File Storage or Blob Storage

There is also another easy way by using readymade solution of marketplace which does all of this for you - https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-in/marketplace/apps/bowspritconsultingopcprivatelimited1596291408582.nsgbackup?tab=Overview

Thanks.